# Estoy modificando un array de listas, mediante parametros de input pero no visualizo los cambios al realizar un format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Copio la función que estoy utilizando con la salida:

```
ListasAlumnos = [['Juan', 'Carmelo', 5, 7, 9, 7], ['Laura', 'Jazmine', 7, 8, 5, 6.66],
                     ['Dario', 'Villalobos', 5, 6, 3, 4.66], ['Marito', 'Tasolo', 4, 7, 9, 6.666],
                     ['Esteban', 'Quito', 9, 9, 8, 8.66]]
Tabla = """\
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nombre    Apellido        Primero Segundo Tercero     Promedio anual|
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
{}

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+\
"""
#Asignamos la tabla el formato y la cantidad de caracteres en cada campo
Tabla = (Tabla.format('\n'.join("| {:<8} {:<10} {:>8} {:>6} {:>7} {:>23} |".format(*fila)
                                for fila in ListasAlumnos)))
print(Tabla)

print("Desea insertar un Cliente nuevo? S/N")
Respuesta = input()
if Respuesta == "S" or Respuesta == "s":
    print("Ingrese Nombre del cliente:")
    Nombre = input()
    print("Ingrese Apellido:")
    Apellido = input()
    print("Ingrese primer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:")
    Primero = int(input())
    print("Ingrese segundo trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:")
    Segundo = int(input())
    print("Ingrese tercer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:")
    Tercero = int(input())
    Promedio = ((Primero + Segundo + Tercero) / 3)
else:
    print("Finalizando insercion de Clientes nuevos....")


ListasAlumnos.append([Nombre, Apellido, Primero, Segundo, Tercero, Promedio])
print(ListasAlumnos)
Tabla = (Tabla.format('\n'.join("| {:<8} {:<10} {:>8} {:>6} {:>7} {:>23} |".format(*fila)
                                for fila in ListasAlumnos)))
print(Tabla)
```

Salida:

> ```
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Nombre    Apellido        Primero Segundo Tercero     Promedio anual|
> |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
> | Juan     Carmelo           5      7       9                       7 |
> | Laura    Jazmine           7      8       5                    6.66 |
> | Dario    Villalobos        5      6       3                    4.66 |
> | Marito   Tasolo            4      7       9                   6.666 |
> | Esteban  Quito             9      9       8                    8.66 |
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
> Desea insertar un Cliente nuevo? S/N
> S
> Ingrese Nombre del cliente:
> Emiliano
> Ingrese Apellido:
> Pichu
> Ingrese primer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:
> 5
> Ingrese segundo trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:
> 5
> Ingrese tercer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:
> 5
> [['Juan', 'Carmelo', 5, 7, 9, 7], ['Laura', 'Jazmine', 7, 8, 5, 6.66], ['Dario', 'Villalobos', 5, 6, 3, 4.66], ['Marito', 'Tasolo', 4, 7, 9, 6.666], ['Esteban', 'Quito', 9, 9, 8, 8.66], ['Emiliano', 'Pichu', 5, 5, 5, 5.0]]
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Nombre    Apellido        Primero Segundo Tercero     Promedio anual|
> |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
> | Juan     Carmelo           5      7       9                       7 |
> | Laura    Jazmine           7      8       5                    6.66 |
> | Dario    Villalobos        5      6       3                    4.66 |
> | Marito   Tasolo            4      7       9                   6.666 |
> | Esteban  Quito             9      9       8                    8.66 |
> +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

El array(`ListasAlumnos`) cuando lo imprime después de realizar el `append` lo inserta pero cuando vuelva a recorrer las filas es como que si no estuviera.

Aclaro: Hace dos semanas empece a incursionarme en Python así que se poco y nada.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que reasignas a la variable `Tabla` la cadena formateada, por lo que en el segundo intento de formateo no hay ninguna diana de reemplazo para `str.format`.

```
Tabla = (Tabla.format('...))
```

Tu código debería ser algo así:

```
TABLA = """\
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nombre    Apellido        Primero Segundo Tercero     Promedio anual|
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
{}

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+\
"""

listas_alumnos = [['Juan', 'Carmelo', 5, 7, 9, 7],
                  ['Laura', 'Jazmine', 7, 8, 5, 6.66],
                  ['Dario', 'Villalobos', 5, 6, 3, 4.66],
                  ['Marito', 'Tasolo', 4, 7, 9, 6.666],
                  ['Esteban', 'Quito', 9, 9, 8, 8.66]
                  ]

# Asignamos la tabla el formato y la cantidad de caracteres en cada campo
tabla = TABLA.format(
    '\n'.join(
        "| {:<8} {:<10} {:>8} {:>6} {:>7} {:>23} |".format(*fila)
        for fila in listas_alumnos
        )
    )

print(tabla)

respuesta = input("Desea insertar un Cliente nuevo? S/N ").lower()
if respuesta == "s":
    nombre = input("Ingrese Nombre del cliente: ")
    apellido = input("Ingrese Apellido: ")
    primero = int(input("Ingrese primer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones: "))
    segundo = int(input("Ingrese segundo trimestre cantidad de Transacciones: "))
    tercero = int(input("Ingrese tercer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones: "))
    promedio = (primero + segundo + tercero) / 3
else:
    print("Finalizando insercion de Clientes nuevos....")


listas_alumnos.append([nombre, apellido, primero, segundo, tercero, promedio])
tabla = TABLA.format(
    '\n'.join(
        "| {:<8} {:<10} {:>8} {:>6} {:>7} {:>23} |".format(*fila)
        for fila in listas_alumnos
        )
    )
print(tabla)
```

Te aconsejo que intentes seguir en lo posible las [convenciones de estilo para código Python marcadas en PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Las variables deben nombrarse usando minúsculas con `_` como separador de palabras. Se reserva `CamelCase` para las clases y `MAYÚSCULAS` para las constantes. No es algo obligatorio, pero estandariza tu código y ayuda a otra gente familiarizada con Python a leerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones y por la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

aqui te paso la solucion...

```
ListasAlumnos = [['Juan', 'Carmelo', 5, 7, 9, 7], ['Laura', 'Jazmine', 7, 8, 5, 6.66],
                     ['Dario', 'Villalobos', 5, 6, 3, 4.66], ['Marito', 'Tasolo', 4, 7, 9, 6.666],
                     ['Esteban', 'Quito', 9, 9, 8, 8.66]]
Tabla = """\
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nombre    Apellido        Primero Segundo Tercero     Promedio anual|
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
{}

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+\
"""
#Asignamos la tabla el formato y la cantidad de caracteres en cada campo
Tabla = (Tabla.format('\n'.join("| {:<8} {:<10} {:>8} {:>6} {:>7} {:>23} |".format(*fila)
                                for fila in ListasAlumnos)))
print(Tabla)

print("Desea insertar un Cliente nuevo? S/N")
Respuesta = input()
if Respuesta == "S" or Respuesta == "s":
    print("Ingrese Nombre del cliente:")
    Nombre = input()
    print("Ingrese Apellido:")
    Apellido = input()
    print("Ingrese primer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:")
    Primero = int(input())
    print("Ingrese segundo trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:")
    Segundo = int(input())
    print("Ingrese tercer trimestre cantidad de Transacciones:")
    Tercero = int(input())
    Promedio = ((Primero + Segundo + Tercero) / 3)
else:
    print("Finalizando insercion de Clientes nuevos....")


ListasAlumnos.append([Nombre, Apellido, Primero, Segundo, Tercero, Promedio])
print(ListasAlumnos)
Tabla = """\
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nombre    Apellido        Primero Segundo Tercero     Promedio anual|
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
{}

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+\
"""
Tabla = (Tabla.format('\n'.join("| {:<8} {:<10} {:>8} {:>6} {:>7} {:>23} |".format(*fila)
                                for fila in ListasAlumnos)))
print(Tabla)
```

Lo único que faltó fue "limpiar" la tabla para que muestre los nuevos datos

Comment: Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones , por la solucion y por la bienvenida.